# Is there a way to know which feature is causing a split or present in root or decision node of a decision tree in Random Forest using Python?

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest, bagging

Let's say I have 100 features f1, f2, .... ,f100 and I want to know if f3, f4, f5 caused any split or were present in a root/decision node of any decision tree in a random forest.

I have close to 200 decision tree and I don't want to view each of these trees manually. I want to write a program in [python](/questions/tagged/python) which checks if f2, f3 or both are present in a tree and ultimately give me the number of trees they are present in.
To be more illustrative, if i have 200 trees, i want to have information like f2 was present in 30 trees while f3 in 20 and so on.

Comment: there are a number of tools to deconstruct the RF and understand why it does what it does.  I like LIME, but there are several tools.  You might get more mileage if you ask the admins to migrate this to artificial intelligence, data science, or stack overflow.